# How to initialize multidimensional associative array with empty values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I want to create and initialize a multidimensional array with known possible keys for the second dimension but no values.

This array will store `event_ids` (populated dynamically) and for each `event_id` an array having exactly four different counts (also filled dynamically).

**Structure I want to create**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array  =================> This index will be the event_id 
        (
            [invitation_not_sent_count] => 
            [no_response_yet_count] => 
            [will_not_attend_count] => 
            [will_attend_count] => 
        )
)
```

**What I did so far?**

```
$DataArray = array();
$DataArray[] = array('invitation_not_sent_count' => '',
                                        'no_response_yet_count' => '',
                                        'will_not_attend_count' => '',
                                        'will_attend_count' => '');
```

And inside the loop I am populating data dynamically like:

```
$DataArray[$result->getId()]['no_response_yet_count'] = $NRCount;
```

What I get is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [invitation_not_sent_count] => 
        [no_response_yet_count] => 
        [will_not_attend_count] => 
        [will_attend_count] => 
    )

[18569] => Array
    (
        [no_response_yet_count] => 2
    )

[18571] => Array
    (
        [no_response_yet_count] => 1
    )
```

)

What I want is that if a value is not available in the iteration, its entry should be empty as defined at initialization time. So if all other counts are empty in the data except `no_response_yet_count`, the array should be:

**Expected Output**

```
Array
(
[18569] => Array
    (
        [invitation_not_sent_count] => 
        [no_response_yet_count] => 2
        [will_not_attend_count] => 
        [will_attend_count] =>
    )

[18571] => Array
    (
        [invitation_not_sent_count] => 
        [no_response_yet_count] => 1
        [will_not_attend_count] => 
        [will_attend_count] =>
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually resort to a mapping function at that point:

```
function pre_map(&$row) {
    $row = array
    (
        'invitation_not_sent_count' => '',
        'no_response_yet_count' => '',
        'will_not_attend_count' => '',
        'will_attend_count' => ''
    );
}
```

Then in the while/for loops:

```
{
    $id = $result->getId();
    if (!isset($DataArray[$id])) { pre_map($DataArray[$id]); }
    $DataArray[$id]['no_response_yet_count'] = $NRCount;
}
```

The `if (!isset($DataArray[$id]))` is to make sure it doesn't wipe out the same index row, in case you happen to re-loop on the same ID. Thus, it will only map it once, then never again in the loop.

There are some other one-line shortcuts like maybe even using array_map(), but I was showing the long version, for full flexibility just in case.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I initialized the array with `$DataArray = array(array());` and after data population in order to remove first empty sub array at  index 0  I used `unset($DataArray['0']);`

Comment: To initialize the $DataArray, all you really need is: `$DataArray = array();`. Since the mapping function adds the secondary array with blank values for you. That way you do not need to pop off the 0 index one.